# Perl one-liner: how to reference the filename passed in when -ne or -pe commandline switches are used

Tags: perl, command-line

In Perl, it's normally easy enough to get a reference to the commandline arguments. I just use `$ARGV[0]` for example to get the name of a file that was passed in as the first argument.

When using a Perl one-liner, however, it seems to no longer work. For example, here I want to print the name of the file that I'm iterating through if a certain string is found within it:

```
perl -ne 'print $ARGV[0] if(/needle/)' haystack.txt
```

This doesn't work, because `ARGV` doesn't get populated when the `-n` or `-p` switch is used. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$ARGV). Quote from [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$ARGV):

```
$ARGV

Contains the name of the current file when reading from <> .
```

So, your one-liner would become:

```
perl -ne 'print $ARGV if(/needle/)' haystack.txt
```

Though be aware that it will print once for *each* match. If you want a newline added to the print, you can use the `-l` option.

```
perl -lne 'print $ARGV if(/needle/)' haystack.txt
```

If you want it to print only once for each match, you can close the ARGV file handle and make it skip to the next file:

```
perl -lne 'if (/needle/) { print $ARGV; close ARGV }' haystack.txt haystack2.txt
```

As Peter Mortensen points out, `$ARGV` and `$ARGV[0]` are two different variables. `$ARGV[0]` refers to the first element of the array `@ARGV`, whereas `$ARGV` is a scalar which is a completely different variable.

You say that `@ARGV` is not populated when using the `-p` or `-n` switch, which is not true. The code that runs silently is something like:

```
while (@ARGV) {
    $ARGV = shift @ARGV;           # arguments are removed during runtime
    open ARGV, $ARGV or die $!; 
    while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {  # long version of: while (<>) {
        # your code goes here
    } continue {                   # when using the -p switch
        print $_;                  # it includes a print statement
    }
}
```

Which in essence means that using `$ARGV[0]` will never show the real file name, because it is removed before it is accessed, and placed in `$ARGV`.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between $ARGV[0] and $ARGV should be explained. And why the former, but not the latter, works in this particular case.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't suppose it would hurt.

Comment: How can I print the file together with e.g. the matching line, for example in the command `perl -ne 'print "$ARGV: $line" if /pattern/' $(grep -rl "pattern")`, what should I place instead of *$line*?